# Neo4j - Calculate similarity and Insert a new relationship between nodes if not exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Edited:**
 I need to check whether the relationship exists or not. If not exists then calculate similarity between nodes, which is bit time taking. And then, i need to insert the relation ship between them.
 I need to do the repeat this for all the pair of nodes in the graph.

Programmatic paradigm for this scenario is like:

```
 If relationship exits
     then calculate similarity and insert relationship
 else
     do nothing (or) return value
```

There is also problem with this query is, it may also cause memory exceptions. If so, how to overcome this problem.

This is my query,

```
MATCH (a{word:"review"}),(b{word:"nothing"}) 
MERGE  (a)-[r:jsim]->(b)
MERGE  (a)<-[s:jsim]-(b)
SET r.val = 
  CASE WHEN NOT (HAS (r.val)) 
    THEN [1]
  ELSE 2 END 
SET s.val = 
  CASE WHEN NOT (HAS (s.val)) 
    THEN [2]
  ELSE 1 END 
RETURN r,s
```

In my actual problem, the FALSE case has a big query which iterate through all the nodes in the graph which has to store many values in the stack. So, here the memory exception may arise.

My IF ELSE CASE query is :

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) where r.val>1
WITH collect(DISTINCT b.word) as our_word_pairs,a
MATCH (c)-[r]->(d) where r.val>1 AND Not c = a
WITH collect(DISTINCT d.word) as other_word_pairs,a,c,our_word_pairs
WITH FILTER(X in our_word_pairs where X in other_word_pairs) AS word_pair_intersection,
(our_word_pairs+other_word_pairs) AS all_word_pairs,other_word_pairs,a,c,our_word_pairs
WITH DISTINCT(all_word_pairs) as all_word_pairs,word_pair_intersection,a,c
WITH (1.0*SIZE(word_pair_intersection)/SIZE(all_word_pairs)) AS jsim
```

Now the **jsim** is the value I need to assign.

Assume a and b are two nodes, I have to find similarity between them and add the relationship with the value. Similarity of A and B is the common nodes between them divided by the total no.of nodes they are connected with.

```
Ex: A-->p,A-->q.A-->r,A-->s
    B-->r,B-->s,B-->t,B-->u,B-->v

   Sim(A,B) = Common nodes/Total Nodes
            = 2/7
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but don't have enough knowledge to overcome memory exception.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the query to it, in a tiny comment this is not really readable, thanks

Comment: It is difficult to say what causes the exception without knowing how your 'big query' looks like.

Comment: I will edit my question again with the internal query in CASE

Comment: OK. Does the big query alone give you an memory exception?

Comment: Yes - Martin Preusse

Comment: Ok, so the problem is in the big query, not the `CASE`. How does the query look if you `EXPLAIN` it? And can you give us an idea of your graph structure?

Comment: I will edit the question with the big query explanation @Martin Preusse

Comment: OK. With `EXPLAIN` I meant profiling the query to find the specific part which might cause the exception http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html