# Neo4j - How to execute Nested query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to execute a query conditionally inside the **CASE** and assign some value to the temporary variable which helps in resolving my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366621/neo4j-calculate-similarity-and-insert-a-new-relationship-between-nodes-if-not).

Here is my query to do so is returning with syntax error:

```
MERGE(a {word:'review'})-[r:jsim]->(b{word:"nothing"})
ON CREATE set r.temp = false
ON MATCH set r.temp = true
CASE{r.val}  
   WHEN {r.temp} 
       THEN [MATCH (a)-[s]->(b{word:"equal"})
             SET r.val = s.val  
            ]
WITH r, r.temp AS result
REMOVE r.temp
RETURN result
```

My syntax error is:

```
Invalid input 'A': expected 'r/R' (line 4, column 2 (offset: 112))
"CASE r.temp "
  ^
```

My updated query after suggestions:

```
MERGE(a {word:'review'})-[r:jsim]->(b{word:"nothing"})
ON CREATE set r.temp = false
ON MATCH set r.temp = true
WITH r, CASE r.val WHEN r.temp THEN [MATCH (a)-[s]->(b {word:"equal"}) RETURN s.val] ELSE [] END as toDo
UNWIND toDo as val
SET r.val = head(val)
WITH r, r.temp AS result,s
REMOVE r.temp
RETURN result
```

Please help me out debugging this.

Comment: as I told in my anwser, you can not set MATCH in a CASE !

Answer (score 1):

Your CASE statement is wrong :

```
CASE {var}
  WHEN {value} THEN [something]
  WHEN {value2} THEN [something]
  ELSE [something]
END
```

Moreover, I can't understand the meaning of your case, there is only one condition.

Comment: Assume, I have many cases like that. In the "something " part I need to run a match query(originally it is a big query). Edited my query, which is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things here :

a) When setting multiple values on an entity (node/rel), you need a comma `,` for separating them. So here you would need a comma after `set r.temp = true`

b) As mentioned by logisima, the workflow of a case is

```
CASE
 WHEN ..
 THEN ..
 ELSE ..
END
```

However, the `{}` are for example purposes, here you don't need to enclose your variable in `{}`

c) You can not do queries in CASE steps, a workaround is to build a virtual collection for it. I think for your use case this should do the trick :

```
MERGE(a {word:'review'})-[r:jsim]->(b{word:"nothing"})
ON CREATE set r.temp = false
ON MATCH set r.temp = true
WITH r, CASE r.val WHEN r.temp THEN [a] ELSE [] END as toDo
UNWIND toDo as a
MATCH (a)-[s]->(b {word:"equal"})
SET r.val = s.val
WITH r, r.temp AS result
REMOVE r.temp
RETURN result
```

So, the achievement here, is when the CASE condition is true, you will have a collection with the node `a` in it, when false then an empty collection. Which means that the empty will work only on the non-empty collection.

Comment: Instead of a collection, I have to return a scalar value which I need to assign to the r.val . I have to run match queries in the true condition itself. I am extending my question with the new query. And, with the your query, r.temp is not removed. @Christophe Willemsen

Comment: Now I got your logic, @Christophe Willemsen . But a problem with the query is, the temp property which we set is not removed and new value is not set.

Comment: I didn't know it was a temp property

Comment: can you provide some test data for it ?

Comment: How to provide test data?

Comment: I will add couple of MERGE statements in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93519/discussion-between-ashwanth-and-christophe-willemsen).

Answer (score 0):

Does this query work for your use case?

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a { word:'review' })-[r:jsim]->(b { word:"nothing" })
WITH a, r, b, (r IS NOT NULL) AS result
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[s]->({ word:"equal" })
FOREACH (x IN CASE
         WHEN r IS NULL THEN [1]
         ELSE [] END | 
         CREATE ({ word:'review' })-[:jsim]->({ word:"nothing" }))
FOREACH (y IN CASE
         WHEN s IS NOT NULL THEN [1]
         ELSE [] END | 
         SET r.val = s.val)
RETURN result;
```

If the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` fails to find a match, then the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` should not hit the DB, since `a` would be `NULL`.

The first `FOREACH` would only do a `CREATE` if the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` fails. This mimics the `MERGE` behavior.

The second `FOREACH` would only set the `r.val` value if both `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses find matches.